# Why isnt my button displaying value onto the div

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

> I want the **button** with the id of number1 to **display** the **value** of **1** on to the **input box** which has the id of quest which is short for question.I also want to know if my code can be made more readable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calucator</title>
    <style>
        body{
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        const quest = document.getElementById("quest");
        const data = quest.value;
        const yourElement = document.createElement("div");
      
        function nums(){
        const num1 = document.getElementById('number1').innerText = 1;
        data.textContent = num1;
    }
    function run() {
        nums()
        yourElement.textContent = data
        quest.appendChild(yourElement);
    }
    
       </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calucator</h1>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter now" name="" id="quest">
    <button onclick="run()">=</button>
    <br>
    <button onclick="" id="number1">1</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    const quest = document.getElementById("quest");
    const data = quest.value;
    const yourElement = document.createElement("div");
    //PROBLEM 1: You are not attaching yourElement to the DOM. See Element.insertBefore / Element.appendChild
    function nums(){
      const num1 = document.getElementById('number1').innerText = 1;
      data.textContent = num1;
    }
    function run() {
      nums()
      yourElement.textContent = data
      quest.appendChild(yourElement);
    }

   </script>
```

And

```
<button onclick="run()">=</button>
```

Problem 2: Don't use inline element event handling. It isn't safe and Content-Security-Policy won't allow it. Instead, use JavaScript `Element.addEventListener(...)`

Comment: I would also like to add that putting the `<script>` tag into the `<head>` makes it impossible to reference DOM elements via `document.getElementBy...` because they have not rendered yet. Move the `<script>` tag right before closing the `</body>`.